# The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:35439 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, cicd, kind

I have installed `Kind` for local Kubernetes deployment.
I want to make a connection with Jenkins using the kube config file as a secret in Jenkins cloud but getting an error on `Test Connection`
`Error testing connection : java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:35439`

`kubectl config view`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:35439
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

but when I view file from this path `cat ~.kube/config` then getting this file with base64

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://127.0.0.1:35439
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFb3dJQkFBS0NBUUVBcTdoNmcyaGVDRTZzRlR3Z3FsbkdtVUFuWlUvNUg4UnhvOEhiNGhpWlFVYkJQeWE5ClRoUGZidUI4TGhNTUd5UER6eExUQ0htTHpEZkJMSFhDK3MyWjRiTk9JYnlrNXlDdG94YUg2QVVlY3R4aWlKWk4KM2ZWanNsaC9MbDBGek1UVlVCQ0Q3bDYzSDdqdWE5NGJPNkV4WDFqdWFTbjhVOU1XamkwWmk3TWZBVjRLS1dEdApXZXJyOVNZZDdjV0MxZStnVUVCakp2Y1ZWSHdrRU1tWWtJZGNXYW1UZGVjUGVBUFJ0aGxsbGZHYzUxSlBUcWltCk1CY1phSmpaL1BKTHhzcWVCQWhHZlJxaFAxRXVXT2VIY2VaL3Y5ZHE3YU9WL2VYVkJVTTRzTjhvdXVVYk00MFcKWjF4TWhHendNWjJLeWx5ZjRYVDM3My9hczZ6cGZPZ25QajVoTFFJREFRQUJBb0lCQUZKcWdmSmJ2dlhCdkhtYwptQmpxYVpUWDQ1Q09aNFRGcGJ6d3AvWEYxSmd0dTBYeDg5MXJVRXRJMXBET2QzcjNHVjFqTFlIZHhDakpnWjh6CkRkZU5vaE5mR1ZxN3pYRllqNzI4YkpJQkV2SVJzQURhRXBrNjB4U2Z3THFoenN6T2s0cVB3cUkvTnlpMGUwbXUKR2VmdW4yR2hyeHN1R1hxcHp5T0JwY2NVdXdiT01CRVhCUTlqU29YQTFYeTRMK2xZcXhWbTFEaTJ2Z3h0UDZleAo0bUhOTzdsc2greldqdTBuMjR0Z1YyT0dweFBuQ0E3MFROZWx6UkJjV25ORUxuSHVLT3lKRnN3OHdEOGtnVlFhCmJKdzdlbkRzUldob1RkRnZ1OEFGMy9HeTZpNDEyT0xwbis1Y3pBbFdZYk5WQkNCL1lIRE9yenFFY2dBeEUxZXgKSzhjZzIwRUNnWUVBM0owZGRRRVhPSUFsMkxscExTdUNHYXhXdWtIMm9pOWI1ZEUyUGpIc3VmcG9VMnhnR1M4dQppbVRlMEFQKzlUQWQvbEd2VFFHU2xEWjY2WjdDWVZnWkwrNTUzU3ZkZU54TWNyd0R0Sjh3N1lTbENFaEV3YnlOClEwRjlGa2xUY2s0MXJJN0lqRFFvN1A1WHVGVE1PU3VNYWlJT0w0VmlkVTNVc2pwZmNaRGxnNVVDZ1lFQXgwTzAKYjdkcC9uMHBWRGRid29DalhvUGMwZFkydHF2K0pBQStIMFNEa3BQTUh1NzFQdUt6UUozNnRFVmdobVA5M2gzRgpUMklJRGc3RU5aM1Q5eFJNUWNWQ0V3Q0JSckpoODU2ZURTUVFqdXh3ZDBmWFJDcTFFTzJ0Q00yVmV1L0EzMzJ5CmJxQW9ibWFJZ1VjS1UrK09FTnhkNE85dW9sSDZIQ0tMU1M3K2dUa0NnWUVBcWJrSjk0RHVUMTV2UDJ0dEdmNFYKNmhCbTdJWmc2dWRLYU9UcU9URUpjUTdQZ2hhblc5aXJrbmNGMzd5alFoaFJpdDFtNHZScHd6S2ludWF2bmxvNwpqbCtHUzN3NnQ0ZXNITHkra1EvRGdZZUJ1M3gxd1NLQS94UDcydEJ3clVpMERGd1F0NlJOTS81OGwraE04VktxCmhPQk1UNHpyY1ZsK1g5dCtvQTBjTlgwQ2dZQkgxelVhZ2ZvSThuOFFDZFZmVHBtWDNkcWpIS1FsUCtVa2ZhSG8KQy8rVHZRMStxWkJwMTduZ3RoUkpJaW9teWE0aGiodvSThtSTltNGhRRGNKK1hHUTVWT0JVV1hMdy9ETmtieURnYgpiTUU3aGlzV0ZpU2FRdnQ4MnZQamxKc3I4M3lLRnZ0WnZ3eFVvVXJkc1FzY0wrWDhWamJTZmdCWkxVMExEN2svCjdWMThvUUtCZ0RvQVZsZHdZblJkbVdmcjRWZXRiRlVxQ2JWV3Z3UjR5RFpvSWVzdDRTMXJzY1ppTmNlVVEyMzUKd2xERVVRNHliT1daYXNDMUNHNlUyUnF6Q1JTZEpJbG00ZEFveTA1dzFOYmkkjkjdoSFJWOFdZZ0RNRWRnRDhoaXIwZgpZYVB5S3hURnAvZTNiYm85emZLNTFaMWprNWxwR3B0S3QzenhML2N6ejFXOEo4czJzTU9KCi0tLS0tRU5EIFJTQSBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCg==
```

Due to this connection is not building with Jenkins through the cloud and I'm not able to run the Kubernetes command in the Jenkins File
This is my Jenkins Deployment stage

```
stage('Deploying App to Kubernetes') {
            steps {
                // Use the kubeconfig credential ID that you added
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'k8s', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {
                    sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'  
                    sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'
                    sh './kubectl config get-contexts'
                    sh './kubectl get nodes'
                    sh './kubectl apply -f deploy/deployment.yaml'
                    sh './kubectl apply -f deploy/service.yaml'
                    sh './kubectl get svc'
                    sh './kubectl get deployments'
                    sh './kubectl get pods'
                }
            }

        }
```

I have a master node with a kind

```
kind get clusters
kind
```

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
kind-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   18h   v1.21.1
```

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:35439
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:35439/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

What could be the issue, I'm not able find the solution and i'm trying this for the last one days and I did not get the proper solution.

Comment: can someone check this issue why it's coming